# How to reload the project after dependencies is added?

Tags: haskell, emacs, spacemacs, intero

During the development, I've added a library to `package.yaml` and the `GHCi` is already started.

For example, I've added the `bytestring` library:

```
executables:
  playground-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - playground
    - text
    - bytestring
```

Because I use it in a file that is called `Families.hs` and it contains the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE  TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}

module Families where

import Data.Word (Word8)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
```

When I try to load the file, it complains:

```
:l ./src/Families.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Families         ( src/Families.hs, interpreted )

src/Families.hs:6:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Data.ByteString’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘bytestring-0.10.8.2’.
    You can run ‘:set -package bytestring’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
6 | import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

The question is, how to reload the whole project into the GHCi and allow usage of `bytestring` library.

**UPDATE**
I also tried with `:reload` and got

```
:reload
[1 of 1] Compiling Families         ( src/Families.hs, interpreted )

src/Families.hs:6:1: error:
    Could not load module ‘Data.ByteString’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘bytestring-0.10.8.2’.
    You can run ‘:set -package bytestring’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
6 | import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Did you try `:reload` ?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that, then. For fast prototyping, I usually do something like this: `stack build --fast --filewatch`.

Comment: I am using spacemacs and do not know, how to restart REPL

Comment: Are you using intero?

Comment: Yes, I am using intero. I followed this instruction http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/haskell/README.html.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Spacemacs along with `intero`. In this case you may restart whole intero process by typing `M-x intero-restart RET`, or `M-RET i r` which will reload all stack dependencies.

Another way to do this is to put your cursor on the error import and type `C-c C-r` to let the `intero` automatically fix the issue.